# How to reset chrome console variables

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

let says I have

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

I want to restart with

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

So how to avoid (without closing and reopening console)

> VM347:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'array' has already been
>   declared
>       at :1:1

Comment: Use ```let``` instead of ```const``` and then just ```array = [....]``` instead of ```const array = [...]```

Comment: [This is now possible](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-92/#const-redeclaration) (June 2021)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, the console is fairly special but it is, fundamentally, an open-ended execution context. You can't redeclare a `const` within the same execution context unless it's in a nested block. (And if you open a nested block in the console, you don't see the content evaluated until you close the block, so that wouldn't help.)

Instead, use `let` and leave off the `let` the second time:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
// ...
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Or if that's a big problem, use `var` since you're allowed to repeat it.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
// ...
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **const** to **var**.

Using const means that the values cannot be changed after being initialized.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

So when you want to change the values do:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

So now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's the same as with the Node.js terminal. If it's declared, you need to reset the context by refreshing the console.

Answer (score 0):

`const` declares a read-only named constant, you should be using the `let` statement in this case as follow:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

// Reassign the value of 'array'
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// Log the result
console.log(array)
```

Result:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```